# How to access day and time in discord.js

Tags: javascript, node.js, discord.js

[3vilBot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8L5XW.png)

See the image this discord bot shows the time the message was sent as footer of embed. Like the next day it changes from today to yesterday like how can i make this?

I wanna do basically the same use the time as a footer.

Please help me

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So there's a method in Discord.js's `MessageEmbed` class, its called `.setTimestamp()`.

`.setTimestamp` allows you to add a timestamp on your embed footer. Here's an example:

```js
const {
    MessageEmbed
} = require('discord.js');

const exampleEmbed = new MessageEmbed()
    .setTitle("Example")
    .setTimestamp(); // This is what you need!
```

Read more about `.setTimestamp` here: https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/stable/class/MessageEmbed?scrollTo=setTimestamp

Comment: Just as an added thing, you can have *both* a footer and a timestamp and djs will sort it all out for you :)

Answer (score 1):

If you want to set the exactly time and day you have to use :

```
var d = new Date,
    dformat = [d.getMonth()+1,
    d.getDate(),
    d.getFullYear()].join('/')+' '+
    [d.getHours(),
    d.getMinutes(),
    d.getSeconds()].join(':');
```

You have to set the `d` in the line you want!
If you want to add it in footer you do it like this :

```
.setFooter(d)
```